# Bringing image data and labels together

Tags: python, numpy, glob, imread

I have a mother directory which contains several subfolders in which I stored images of license plates. In the mother directory, there also lies a folder named train Val, whoch is a csv-file which contains labels of the data. trainVal contains the following columns:

- track_id - ID of specific track based on tracker
- image_path - path to image in archive structure
- lp - ground truth text for license plate
- train - Train/test split. 0 - test, 1 - train

[image: TrainVal]

In my opinion, track_id is not necessary for bringing labels (the labels are "lp", the ground truth text, e.g. 7C24698) and license plates together. I am wondering how to get them together.

I read in the images with the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

folders = glob.glob(r'path\to\mother\directory\*')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.png'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
    read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

I read in the trainVal data using this code:

```
import csv

track_id = []
image_path = []
lp = []
train = []

with open(r'path\to\trainVal.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        track_id.append(row[0])
        image_path.append(row[1])
        lp.append(row[2])
        train.append(row[3])
```

Now, I got the labels and all the other data of trainVal as arrays.

Is there a way to bring labels and images together by extending the code I used or do I have to read in the images another way or don't I have to do anything like this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve or replace?

Comment: I want Python to "know" which image belongs to which label. I don't think Python knows which image belongs to which label simply by opening the both files, does it?

Comment: This is quite ambiguous. In your file `trainVal`, column `lp` is your ground truth, and `file_path` leads to your images, so both these fields enable "Python" to "know" which image belongs to which label. Now the next questions are: how do you want this information to be presented (in a list? dictionary?) -- do you know how to open this csv `trainVal`? -- what do you want to do with that data next?

Comment: If what you mean by "Python to know which image belongs to which label" is having a machine learning model to classify images based on your training data, then it's another story and you'll need more tools for that.

Comment: I edited my text above. I know how to read in the csv file as list or as array. And I know, that I need to apply something like a neural network. But I do not get it, how Python will know which image belongs to which label? Do I not have to merge the both datasets? My objective is to let a neural network learn what is on the license plate. And that the neural net is able to learn by itself it needs to know what it should learn. And I still think that therefore we have to bring this labels and the images together in a certain way and I don't get it how to do this. Is that understandable?